# TextView.setText() is working on button press, but not with CountDownTimer

Tags: android, textview, counter, settext

I have a class that implements a few buttons and counters, when I press a button I need some text in a TextView to be set to something else. It isn't anything crazy, which is why I can't understand why it doesn't work.

The button onClick method that works:

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_view);

        Button button_2 = new Button(this);
        button_2.setText("2");
        button_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                setValues(2, 2);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter_label)).setText("You Pressed 2");
                updateScrollText();
                startTimer(200000);
            }
        }
        linLayout.addView(button_2);
    }


    public void setValues(int first, int second);
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
...
```

But when I try to place it in my timer:

```
private void startTimer(long time){
    counter = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000){
        public void onTick(long millisUntilDone){

           Log.d("counter_label", "Counter text should be changed");
           ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter_label)).setText("You have " + millisUntilDone + "ms");                    
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter_label)).setText("DONE!");

        }
    }.start();
}
```

The frustrating part is that the LogCat shows "Counter text should be changed" on every tick like it is supposed to, it just doesn't actually change the text. Any clue what is going on? I have Cleaned the project and everything else works as it should.

I also just noticed that another counter timer that is doing a similar thing (showing me time until it is done) was working 100%, I haven't touched it and now it isn't setting the text either. It stops changing the text after 1 second but the counter keeps counting down.

Comment: post the complete code.

Comment: Updated it, it really is VERY simple. I didn't include the full code for spaces sake, there are a few other buttons included that all work as well and are all set up in the exact same fashion. The other timer is done the exact same, just in startTimerTwo and is done when a different button is pressed. Everything works completely fine, just not updating the text continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Your timer is probably not running on the UI thread but only the UI thread can manipulate the UI. Just wrap you setText as follows (assuming you're in an activity):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter_label)).setText("You have " + millisUntilDone + "ms");
        }
});
```

Comment: No luck, but  an appreciated response.

Comment: @zgc7009 i am surprised your code even runs. coz you have not set the content to the activity.

Comment: @zgc7009 do you not get `NullPointerException` coz you are missing this statement `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot. I could not figure out how to do this!
Yep, "just wrap you setText as follows (assuming you're in an activity)" works perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

I taken code you posted, modified it a little and I have to say it works for me. Check it out:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvCountdown;
Button btnCountdownStarter;

int mFirst;
int mSecond;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvCountdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCountdown);
    tvCountdown.setText("timer");

    btnCountdownStarter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCountdownStarter);
    btnCountdownStarter.setText("button");
    btnCountdownStarter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            setValues(2, 2);

            tvCountdown.setText("You pressed 2");

            startTimer(20*1000);
        }
    });     

    }

    public void setValues(int first, int second) {
        mFirst = first;
        mSecond = second;
    }


    private void startTimer(long time) {
        new CountDownTimer(time, 1*1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvCountdown.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);                
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tvCountdown.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
}
```

}

The only thing I modified was creating two views in xml file but not in onCreate method.
activity_main file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCountdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCountdownStarter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCountdown" />
```